# Datum inheritance with multiple children

Tags: javascript, d3.js

d3.js gives inheritance to the child element if they are selected with `select` from the parent selection with its data bound. How can I do the same way with multiple children -- ie use `selectAll` on parent, and have the data propagated to that child selection? I tried to use `datum(function(d) {return d;})` on the children selection, however that seems to only work once, and when trying to update it returns old data for some reason.

I can solve this by using `select` in a loop for each child, however I'd be happy to find a more elegant approach.

In this fiddle on the left is not working but desired solution, on the right -- working but uglier solution. Press the button to see the different behavior

```js
var oldData = [{
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}, {
  x: 10,
  y: 0
}];
var newData = [{
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}, {
  x: 10,
  y: -5
}];

var lineGen = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });

function case1(data) {
  var sel = d3.select('g.c1')
    .selectAll('g.connection')
    .data(data);
  sel.exit().remove();

  var selEnter = sel.enter()
    .append('g').classed('connection', true);
  selEnter.append('path').classed('real', true);
  selEnter.append('path').classed('mouse-capture', true);
  selEnter.merge(sel)
    .selectAll('path')
    .datum(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return lineGen(d);
    });
}

function case2(data) {
  var sel = d3.select('g.c2')
    .selectAll('g.connection')
    .data(data);
  sel.exit().remove();

  var selEnter = sel.enter()
    .append('g').classed('connection', true);
  selEnter.append('path').classed('real', true);
  selEnter.append('path').classed('mouse-capture', true);
  sel = selEnter.merge(sel);
  sel.select('path.real')
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return lineGen(d);
    });
  sel.select('path.mouse-capture')
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return lineGen(d);
    });
}

function setNewData() {
  case1([newData]);
  case2([newData]);
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr('viewBox', '-5 -10 40 20');

svg.append('g')
  .classed('c1', true);

svg.append('g')
  .classed('c2', true)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(20,0)');

case1([oldData]);
case2([oldData]);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

path.real {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: black;
}

path.mouse-capture {
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke: black;
  opacity: 0;
}

g:hover path.real {
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="setNewData()">new data</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately what you want is not possible, unless one changes `d3-selection` source code.

As you know, `selectAll`, unlike `select`, does not propagates the data. For the other readers to understand this issue as well, here is table I made that summarises the differences between `select` and `selectAll`:

| Method | select() | selectAll() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Selection | selects the first element that matches the selector string | selects all elements that match the selector string |
| Grouping | Does not affect grouping | Affects grouping |
| Data propagation | Propagates data | Doesn't propagate data |

So, your `function case1` approach is between a rock and a hard place, because:

- If you use `selectAll` alone, it will not propagate the data;
- If you use `selectAll` with `datum` it will just access the old datum (as you discovered) for the selected elements;
- If you use `selectAll` with `data` returning the datum
  wrapped in an array it will return the datum **just once** (in your case, just for the first path), which is expected because it's the group's parent datum. If you put a `console.log(i)` inside a `datum(d,i)` you'll see that `i` is always `0`.

However, just as a curiosity, there ***is*** a way to do what you want in `function case1`, but it's uglier than `function case2` (which, by the way, is the idiomatic D3): getting the datum directly from the parent.

Like this:

```
.datum(function(d) {
    return d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var oldData = [{
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}, {
  x: 10,
  y: 0
}];
var newData = [{
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}, {
  x: 10,
  y: -5
}];

var lineGen = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });

function case1(data) {
  var sel = d3.select('g.c1')
    .selectAll('g.connection')
    .data(data);
  sel.exit().remove();

  var selEnter = sel.enter()
    .append('g').classed('connection', true);
  selEnter.append('path').classed('real', true);
  selEnter.append('path').classed('mouse-capture', true);
  selEnter.merge(sel)
    .selectAll('path')
    .datum(function(d) {
      return d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
    })
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return lineGen(d);
    });
}

function case2(data) {
  var sel = d3.select('g.c2')
    .selectAll('g.connection')
    .data(data);
  sel.exit().remove();

  var selEnter = sel.enter()
    .append('g').classed('connection', true);
  selEnter.append('path').classed('real', true);
  selEnter.append('path').classed('mouse-capture', true);
  sel = selEnter.merge(sel);
  sel.select('path.real')
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return lineGen(d);
    });
  sel.select('path.mouse-capture')
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return lineGen(d);
    });
}

function setNewData() {
  case1([newData]);
  case2([newData]);
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr('viewBox', '-5 -10 40 20');

svg.append('g')
  .classed('c1', true);

svg.append('g')
  .classed('c2', true)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(20,0)');

case1([oldData]);
case2([oldData]);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

path.real {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: black;
}

path.mouse-capture {
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke: black;
  opacity: 0;
}

g:hover path.real {
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="setNewData()">new data</button>
</body>
```